# Refactor foreach loop to List<T>.ForEach(...)

Tags: c#, list, foreach

Given:

```
foreach (var obj in _data)
{
    maxRows++;
    foreach (var param in obj.Parameters)
        maxRows++;
}
```

I'm trying to convert this into (preferably) one single statement.  Not for any reason in particular, just curious if it's easy enough to mentally parse, and if possible.

```
_data.ForEach(feObj => maxRows++);
_data.ForEach(feObj => feObj.Parameters.ForEach(feParam => maxRows++));
```

This seems to accomplish the same thing, though it would seemingly be less efficient than the original due to iterating through _data an additional time.

Is there a way to combine the two actions within the two separate lines into a single statement?

Comment: `ForEach` isn't Linq.  But you could do `_data.ForEach(obj => {maxRows++; obj.Parameters.ForEach(param => maxRows++);});`

Comment: Your statements are not equivalent.  In your first code with the `foreach` block, you have a nested loop.  In the code with `_data.ForEach` you're running the loops one after the other.  Two completely different code executions.

Comment: @Draken No, because the return type of `++` isn't a `bool`.

Comment: @juharr sorry what is the correct term?  Lambda?

Comment: @Kritner, LINQ is just a library of useful extensions, like `Select`, `Where`, `First`, `Any`, that run against any `IEnumerable<T>`.  There *is* an extension `ForEach` on `List<T>`, but it's not in the LINQ library, so it's not really a LINQ extension.  The `Q` in LINQ stands for Query, which is what the library offers.  `ForEach` isn't generally a query, but an action to take on each item in a collection.  That's why it isn't in the base `LINQ` library.

Comment: @Kritner I guess you could call it a functional method?  Personally I think it's an abomination since it's really not better than a regular `foreach`.  You can read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/)  to understand why there isn't a "Linq" `ForEach`.

Comment: @Jonesopolis `ForEach` isn't an extension method on `List<T>`.  It's just a regular class method.

Comment: righto, good call.  I'd argue that I did know that, and got carried away with adding words to that comment, but would anyone really believe me.

Comment: @Jonesopolis I totally believe you.

Comment: I guess I never really looked at the signature differences between say `Select(...)` and `ForEach(...)`  Looking now, I can see that it is in fact a baked in of `List<T>`.  Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in the same loop.

```
_data.ForEach(feObj => 
 {
    maxRows++;
    feObj.Parameters.ForEach(feParam => maxRows++);
 });
```

Moreover, if you are just adding the count you should do as what @Rob had answered. If any other logic you can put it within the braces.

Comment: thanks, the count was an example and Rob's would work had that been my endgoal.  Your syntax (and I guess originally) @Juharr's was what I was actually looking for.  Guess that really doesn't make it any different looking than my original nested foreach loops.

Answer (score 10):

You can just take the Sum:

```
maxRows += _data.Sum(obj => 1 + obj.Parameters.Count())
```